# Best way to perform a key drivers analysis

Tags: regression, correlation, python, r-squared, importance

I am trying to perform a key driver analysis. I have performed a simple OLS regression on my dataset using the statsmodels api on python. It gives me the desired results, but I am not sure if regression handles multi-collinearity? I am now looking at performing a relative weight analysis (RWA) to understand and check if the results would differ.

From what I understand the RWA method performs an orthogonal transformation of our features by creating a diagonal matrix with the Eigen values of the correlation matrix. However, I have negative correlation values, and negative values in this diagonal matrix leading to NaN values while trying to compute the relative weights.

How do I go about this? Will taking the absolute values in the correlation matrix help since the effect they have on the target variable would still be the same but in a different direction?

Ps: There are a lot of packages on R to perform the key driver analysis. But I couldn't find a reliable one for python.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dominance-analysis` which has method for linear regression.

https://pypi.org/project/dominance-analysis/

The dominance approach is quite similar to [RWA](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428104266017) though some believe it to be a preferred approach as RWA is [biased](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00273171.2014.905766).

If your model is reasonably small, the dominance approach should execute in a reasonable amount of time and the general dominance statistics should provide data that can be used as a surrogate for relative weights.

Answer (score 0):

I work break this out into two component steps. First,
check for multicollinearity separately using variance inflation factor via

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
```

Once multicollinear factors/features with VIF >5 are removed (as general rule of thumb), then run those factors/features with target through this key driver analysis via this [key-driver-analysis](https://pypi.org/project/key-driver-analysis/) python package.